# Container / Component not updating after state change

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, redux

I have been working on integrating Redux into my React Native app. I am stuck on getting an async database fetch to update the necessary components.

I can see that the database call is fetching the data, and that it returns the state correctly (checked using `redux-logger`). However my check for `isFetching` being false never evaluates in the container. I think there is something up with how i've declared the `mapStateToProps` method as its not triggering an update.

I've checked that I am not mutating the state in my reducer!

**UPDATE**:

It often seems to be the seemingly insignificant part I leave out that ends up being the root of the problem. I now see that it is NavigatorIOS that is the issue. Any props passed in via `passProps` do not get updated along with the state. It seems to be a known issue: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/795

**The Action:**

```
export function fetchItems() {
  return function(dispatch) {
    dispatch({ type: 'REQUEST_ITEMS' })


    AsyncDatabaseCall()  
    .then((res) => {
      // console.log (res.rows)
      dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_ITEMS_SUCCESS', data: res })
      // *** Execution reaches here ***
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
      dispatch({ type: 'RECEIVE_ITEMS_FAILURE', error: err })
    })
```

**The Reducer:**

```
var initialState = {
  isFetching: true,
  rows: []
}

export default function items(state = initialState, action = {}) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'REQUEST_ITEMS':
      return Object.assign({}, state, { 
        isFetching: true 
      });
    case 'RECEIVE_ITEMS_SUCCESS':
      // *** Execution reaches here ***
      return Object.assign({}, state, { 
        isFetching: false,
        rows: action.data.rows,
        lastUpdated: action.receivedAt
      });
    case 'RECEIVE_ITEMS_FAILURE':
      return Object.assign({}, state, { 
        isFetching: false, 
        error: action.error 
      });

    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

**The Container:**

```
class ItemIndex extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log ("isFetching")
    console.log (this.props.items.isFetching)
  }

  render() {
    if (this.props.items.isFetching) {
      //render loading screen
      console.log ("will be loading...")
      return (
        <View/>
      )
    } else {
      console.log ("got the data") // execution never reaches here
      return (
        <Items {...this.props} />
      )
    }
  }
};

module.exports = ScaleIndex;
```

The container with the `connect` method:

```js
class MyApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <MainContainer {...this.props} />
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { item, items } = state
  return {
    item,
    items,
    isFetching: items.isFetching
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return { actions: bindActionCreators({ ...DatabaseActions, ...ItemActions }, dispatch) }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyApp)
```

The **MainComponent** container which gives **ItemIndex** as its `initialRoute`:

```
class MainComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }

  render() {
    const { actions, item, items, dispatch } = this.props
    console.log ("MainComponent items")
    console.log (items) // <-- this gets updated on state change
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        ref = "nav"
        style = {styles.navigator}
        initialRoute = {{
          passProps: { actions: actions, item: item, items: items, dispatch: dispatch },
          title: 'Items',
          component: ItemIndex
        }}
        /> 
    )
  }
}
```

..and finally the **root Container**:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super (props)
    // Load all items first.
    store.dispatch(fetchItems())
  }

  render() {
    console.log ("store.getState:")
    console.log (store.getState())
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MyApp />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Do your action types match?

Comment: @NaderDabit Yes they do! Typo.. thanks :)